# C# WPF Syncfusion Selected row doesnt highlight when row is moved to top

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion WPF Datagrid to display some data. I have implemented features to move selected rows up, down, to the top, and to the bottom of the Datagrid. When the row is moved the row should still be selected, this works for up, down, and to bottom but for some reason does not work for moving the row to the top of the data grid.
I have provided the code below and I should point out that the line of code to keep the selected row highlighted is the same for up, down, and to bottom.

```cs
public void PriorityMoveTop()
{
    Job? SelectedRow = (Job)this.jobListView.SelectedItem;
    if (SelectedRow == null)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Job? myJobAfterSelectedRow = (from x in Memory.Jobs where x.Priority == (SelectedRow.Priority - 1) select x).FirstOrDefault();

        if (jobListView.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Operation operation in SelectedRow.Operations)
            {
                operation.Priority = SelectedRow.Priority;
            }
            OrderPriorityColumnDown();
            SelectedRow.Priority = 1;
        }
    }
    SetDataGridJobList();
    if (SelectedRow == null)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        //Code to highlight row
        jobListView.SelectedIndex = SelectedRow.Priority - 1;
    }
}
```

This is my function method to move the row to the top of the Datagrid. Can anyone point me in the right direction of where I have gone wrong with this line of code?

```cs
jobListView.SelectedIndex = SelectedRow.Priority - 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the help of the Syncfusion Team.

I created a method in my Datagrid User control class:

```
public void MoveToTopRow()
{
    var getSelectedIndex = 0;
    jobListView.SelectedIndex = getSelectedIndex;
}
```

I then called this method on the button click in my MainWindow class:

```
private void btnArrowTop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    jobListView.PriorityMoveTop();
    jobListView.MoveToTopRow();
    jobListView.SetDataGridJobList();
    jobListView.MoveToTopRow();
}
```

Maintaining the selection after resetting the ItemSource fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that when a row is moved to the top of the Priority value is zero in SelectedRow. In this case, the SelectedIndex is set as -1. The selected row is not highlighted when SelectedIndex value is -1 in SfDataGrid. This is the behavior of SfDataGrid. So, can you please check the SelectedIndex value when a row is moved to the top of the SelectedRow.Priority.

Comment: Yeah, the SelectedIndex value changes from -1 to 0 when it is moved to the top